# I'm going to analyzing the data using python for get prediction

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

This gave me below error

```
At line:1 char:1
+ from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
```

Comment: You appear to be typing Python code directly into PowerShell...

Answer (score 1):

To run Python code, you should use a Python environment such as the Python interpreter or an integrated development environment (IDE) like Visual Studio Code, PyCharm, or Jupyter Notebook (if you want to run commands line by line).

Answer (score 0):

Name of the file should be something like data.py
Additionally you should have pip install to your pc.
I recommend: Vscode with python 3.7+ installed and pip.

1. Create a file named data.py
2. Open a terminal and run `pip install scikit-learn`
3. Now go to the file and put the code
4. Happy coding